# Duplicate Windows Entries

Tags: refind

I'm dual booting Elementary OS and Windows. I'm seeing two Windows entries though and I'm not sure where refind is finding them.

One is shown as `Boot Microsoft EFI boot from ESP` and the other is `Boot bootmgfw.efi from ESP`. Selecting either of them boots with *Starting from bootmgfw.efi Using load options ''*

My efi directory looks like

```
/boot/efi/
    Boot/
        BCD
        bcd.trunc
        bootfix.bin
        boot.sdi
        bootsect.exe
        en-us/ 
        Fonts/
        Resources/
    bootmgfw.efi
    bootmgr
    bootmgr.efi
    EFI/
        Boot/
        dell/
        Microsoft/
            Boot/
                bootmgfw.efi
                bootmgr.efi
                lots of other files
            Recovery/
                BCD
                BCD.LOG
                BCD.LOG1
                BCD.LOG2
        PEBoot/
        refind/
        tools/
        ubuntu/
    startup.nsh
```

My `refind.conf` has the the entry `dont_scan_dirs EFI/dell,EFI/PEBoot,EFI/ubuntu,EFI/Boot`

I've tried adding `EFI/Microsoft` to `dont_scan_dirs` but both of them still show up.

My disks look like:

[image: sda]
[image: sdb]

I've tried setting `dont_scan_volumes` to `WINRETOOLS,Image,DELLSUPPORT` but that doesn't keep both entries from showing up.

Any ideas on what I can include in my conf file so that only one Windows entry shows up?

Comment: I see that you have two files: `/boot/efi/bootmgfw.efi` and `/boot/efi/bootmgr.efi` which are at the same level as the `EFI` directory. Could rEFInd be reading those, since they are _not_ excluded in the `dont_scan_dirs` list, as you had it originally and in the reported test variations? Another possibility is that the `dont_scan_dirs` exclusion doesn't exclude the named tree, only the named directory. So, excluding `EFI/Microsoft` _is not_ excluding `EFI/Microsoft/Boot`. Try explicitly excluding `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` in the `dont_scan_dirs` list.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Looks like specifying `Boot` was it. If you want write that as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dont_scan_dirs` list is a list of `directories` to skip when looking for `efi` files. Excluding a directory does not appear to exclude the entire tree at that point. Directories under an excluded one are still searched, just `efi` files in that explicitly named directory are ignored.

To solve the issue you'll need to include the directories that have the `efi` files you *don't* want loaded. In your specific case that means adding `EFI/Microsoft/Boot` to the `dont_scan_dirs` list.